# Custom method, related to model

Tags: cakephp, methods

Can you help me how to develop custom methods in CakePHP framework.

I found this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169512/cakephp-custom-global-function) in stackoverflow, but it's global, it's not "model related".

Can you help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you know how to write a method in Object Oriented PHP (you're actually doing it all the time in CakePHP), this shouldn't be any problem. Where are you stuck?

Comment: no problem with oo. where to put code? in controller?

Comment: Well, what do you want to write? If it's "model related", put it in the model in `app/models/[modelname].php`...

Comment: I'm certain that your intentions are good, however if you don't express the ability/desire to help yourself you will find it hard pressed to get satisfactory answer on StackOverflow as well as other sites on the internet. Read this article on the right way to ask questions on the Internet to have the best opportunity for a valuable answer. (http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) Avoid becoming this: http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/

Answer (score 0):

If the code is related to the retrieval or 'serving' of data, put it in the appropriate **model**.

If you are writing code that is going to do something with or without that data, ultimately for display on a webpage, put it in the **controller**.

If you're manipulating data for display - e.g. looping over an array of results to build a table (see a standard CakePHP index.ctp for an example) or if you're simply echoing data to display or using helpers to build a page, then it goes in the view (.ctp).

This is all well covered in the first three chapters of the [book](http://book.cakephp.org).