# Cakephp 2.61 and comboboxes

Tags: mysql, cakephp, combobox

Using Cakephp 2.6.1, I have successfully captured and stored single characters in my database using the following code

```
echo $this->Form->input('grade', array('options' => array( 'G' => 'Good', 'P' => 'Pass','R'=>'Practice Required','F'=>'Fail')));
```

What I would like to know is how to convert these values back to the display values when retrieving them from the database, ie if the database contains 'P', I want to display 'Pass' in the view and index pages.

I'm certain the answer is simple and straightforward, and sheepishly apologise in advance for my ignorance.

Comment: If you can't/want use a model and relations for your grades, you might want to have a look at (fake) "enums": **http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes** | **http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcakephp%5D+enum**

Answer (score 0):

**Step-1**

Create two new files under Vendor folder.

1. master-arrays.php
2. common-functions.php

and Import this two files

*Process of import :*

Dir : app\Config\bootstrap.php

Add this two lines:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'common-functions');

App::import('Vendor', 'master-arrays');
```

**Step-2**

Now open 'master-arrays.php'
and add this array

```
function grade_type()
{
    $GRADE_TYPE['G']  = 'Good';
    $GRADE_TYPE['P'] = 'Pass';
    return $GRADE_TYPE;
}
```

**Step-3**

Change your view -

```
echo $this->Form->input('grade', array('options' =>grade_type())));
```

**Step-4**

Now add this function in 'common-functions.php'

```
    function id_to_text($id, $arr_master=array()) {
    $txt_selected = "";
    $id = ''.$id;      //Added this as it was creating some warnings online for wrong parameter types
    if(is_array($arr_master) && array_key_exists($id,$arr_master)) {
        $txt_selected = $arr_master[$id];
    } else {
        $txt_selected = "";
    }   
    return $txt_selected;
}
```

**Step-5**

In Controller or in view

***Input:***
    id_to_text('P',grade_type());

**Output:**
Pass

Comment: If at all, such data and logic should go into models and helpers.

Comment: This is my way to do that globally. You can use at your won way by using the logic

Comment: Do whatever you like, but don't expect that promoting bad practices is being passed without comment here on SO.

Comment: I think this is not a bad practices. Why you say that please explain.

Comment: That seems incredibly complex for such a simple question.: to those who frowned on his answer, what is the 'correct' way to do it? Surely this sort of thing is bread-and-butter coding and must have been coded thousands of times.

Comment: yes this is complex that I know but in future if you have another array like this than what you did? you write code for every time you need?

Comment: You are placing model and view related logic into global functions, if you don't understand why this is bad practice, then you should get a grasp on programming princinples first before using MVC-ish frameworks like CakePHP.

Comment: @ndm give the ans of the ques. please

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    // In controller
    function fun()
    {
        $grade = array(
            'G' => 'Good',
            'P' => 'Pass',
            'R' => 'Practice Required',
            'F' => 'Fail'
        );
        $this->set('grade', $grade);
        if ($this->request->data) {
            $key = $this->request->data['Model']['grade'];
            $this->request->data['Model']['grade'] = $grade[$key];
            $this->Model->save($this->request->data);
        }
    }

    // in view

    echo $this->Form->input('grade', array(
        'options' => $grade
    ));
```

**Updated Code**

```
// add in Model 
function afterFind($results) {
    foreach ($results as $key => $val) {
        if (isset($val['MyModel']['status'])) {
            $results[$key]['MyModel']['grade_text'] = $this->getGradeText($results[$key]['MyModel']['grade']);
        }
    }
    return $results;
}

public function getGradeText($key)
{
    $grades = array(
            'G' => 'Good',
            'P' => 'Pass',
            'R' => 'Practice Required',
            'F' => 'Fail'
        );
    $txt_selected = "";
    if(array_key_exists($key,$grades)) {
        $txt_selected = $grades[$key];
    } else {
        $txt_selected = "";
    }   
    return $txt_selected;
}

// in controller 

public function index() {
    $this->set('data' , $this->paginate('MyModel'));
}

// in view 

    foreach($data as $value) {

        echo $value['MyModel']['grade_text'];
    }
```

I hope it will be help you.

Comment: Thanks, but that's for an input field. I want to translate the single character to a string on output. I'm surprised that there is not a form helper to do this: It does it one way, from the combobox to the single character, but not the other. I guess I was expecting a form helper function to which I passed an array to do the translation the other way.

Comment: oks, see the following  linlk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169512/cakephp-custom-global-function